# javascript regexp does not evaluate only one character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using this regexp:

```
/[^+][a-z]/.test(str)
```

I'm trying to ensure that if there are any letters (`[a-z]`) in a string (`str`) not proceeded by a plus (`[^+]`) , a match is found and therefore it will return  true.

It mostly works except when there is only one character in the string. For example, `a` returns *false*, even though there is no plus sign preceding it. 
How can I ensure it works for all strings including one character strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `^` as an alternative to `[^+]`:

```
/(?:^|[^+])[a-z]/.test(str)
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:^|[^+])` is a [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) group matching either the start of the string (with `^`) or (`|`) any char other than `+` (with `[^+]`).

Comment: ah - didn't know to do that. thanks.  Also the links explaining the alternative you presented was very helpful. thanks again.